# Google Sheets: Change background color of cell using content of another cell

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I have a google sheet as above where I am typing in colour codes in a hex format and then naming them. I would like to automatically update the Colour Block column's background colour with the hex code in the code column.

Script I have tried, but setBackground function doesn't work.

```
function myFunction() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var cells = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    for(n = 1; n < cells.length; n++) {
        var cell = cells[n];
        cell[n][2].setBackground(cell[n][1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did manage to make this work with the following:

```
function myFunction() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var values = range.getValues();
    for(r = 1; r < values.length; r++) {
        var row = values[r];
        var code = row[1];
        range.getCell(r+1,3).setBackground(code);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works?  My cells are in Column H and I need the output to be in Column G

Comment: @TimCooley You're probably going to want to change the `var code = row[1]` line to perhaps `var code = row[7]` (though you may need to mess around with that value), and then the `range.getCell(r+1,7)` will need changing too. This is just a guess though so you may need to play around with the values.

Comment: @TimCooley did you get it to work? I have no idea how to use this function. I only know about entering formulas inside of the cells. If anyone would be willing to share a sample sheet that would be awesome.