# How To set the Background Color of Values From One Sheet To the Cells with matching Values in Another Sheet with Google Apps Script? EDIT Section add

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, colors

### Problem:

I'm trying to do the following:

Set the same background colors from cells in Sheet2 to the cells in Sheet1 that do have the same values as in Sheet2.

The idea is to compare all the values from Sheet2 that are also present in Sheet1, and take the premade backgrounds from cells in Sheet2 and set those premade backgrounds from Sheet2 to the cells with matching values in Sheet1.

The goal is automatically set the backgrounds based on the cells values when matching regardless of order (to avoid having to do it manually for hundreds of different matching values).

### Illustration example:

In Sheet2, I have preset a range A1:A10 with 10 different values all with their unique background.

[image: Sheet2: range A1:A10]

In Sheet1, I have the same 10 values as in Sheet2 and also other non matching values. Also, the 10 matching values in Sheet1 are 'scattered around' in range A1:AG20 (different range from Sheet2, could be any range).

[image: Sheet1: range A1:AG20]

The result I'm trying to get would be:

[image: Sheet1: backgrounds match]

### Other Close Questions:

I've found close questions here:

[Copying background color from cells on a different tab of the same sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093262/copying-background-color-from-cells-on-a-different-tab-of-the-same-sheet?rq=1)

and here:

[Google Sheets: Change background color of cell using content of another cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892422/google-sheets-change-background-color-of-cell-using-content-of-another-cell)

and here:

[Change cell value based on the cell's background color in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65266797/change-cell-value-based-on-the-cells-background-color-in-google-sheets)

### My Script So far:

Based on those other questions, I've come up with this code:

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  const rngsh2 = sheet2.getRange("A1:A10");
  const colorssh2 = rngsh2.getBackgroundObjects();
  const valuessh2 = rngsh2.getValues();

  const sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const rngsh1 = sheet1.getRange("A1:G20");
  const valuessh1 = rngsh1.getValues();

  if(valuessh2 == valuessh1){
    sheet1.getRange(rngsh1).setBackgroundObjects(colorssh2);
  }
  
}
```

But it's not setting the backgrounds.

### The Sample Sheet:

Here the [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bUoqOMCAsW2-al6NhgmzEEEfEfL6Sip6yijkq5K_XO8/edit?usp=sharing)

What's wrong in the code above?

Many thanks for your help!

### Checked Documentation:

I've checked and tried those references:

[getBackgroundObjects(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getBackgroundObjects())

[setBackground(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#setBackground(String))

[setBackgroundObject(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#setBackgroundObject(Color))

[setBackgrounds(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#setbackgroundscolor)

### EDIT:

[taylor.2317](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17554728/) answer made me realize I had forgotten to say that values in Sheet1 will repeat, and colors need the same background to the repetitions as well (should make no difference in the code for the specified range A1:AG20):

Here are new screenshot showing the repeated values:

Sheet2 input:

[image: Sheet2: Range A1:A10]

The result I'm trying to get with repeated values in Sheet1 would be:

[image: Sheet1: range A1:AG20 (with repetitions of matching values)]

The current Sheet1 result:

[image: Sheet1: range A1:AG20 (with repetitions of matching values not colored)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function copycolors() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const cA = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().flat();//values
  const bA = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()).getBackgrounds().flat();//colors
  let colors = {pA:[]};
  cA.forEach((c,i) => {
    colors[c]=bA[i];
    colors.pA.push(c);
  });
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs = osh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const bs = osh.getDataRange().getBackgrounds();
  let bgA = vs.map((r,i) =>{
    r.forEach((c,j) =>{
      let idx = colors.pA.indexOf(c);
      if(~idx) {
        bs[i][j] = colors[c];
      }
    });
    return bs[i];
  });
    
  osh.getRange(1,1,bgA.length,bgA[0].length).setBackgrounds(bgA);

}
```

[~ bitwise not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT)

Comment: it works! You rock many thanks! I'll need to study your function in details as it's higher level than mine. Here a new sample sheet with your code for new visitors: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wKqdSwHDy8LNiue_zGlK3nGVLirUPGxVo_XqDQW-Dj4/edit#gid=742807159

Comment: Spend some time thinking about the colors object.  It is the basic solution for many different types of spreadsheet issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the bitwise not reference. I just learned about it! Amazing to know! Be well and take care!

Answer (score 1):

```
=Sheet1!A1=Sheet2!A1
```

5 Steps:

1. Select the cell, e.g. `A1`
2. Go to Format, Conditional Formatting
   [image: Fig.1]
3. Under Format Rules, scroll to the bottom of the drop-down list to find "Custom Formula is"
   [image: Fig.2]
4. In the text input box, copy and paste the code above
5. To change the colour, use the Formatting options
   [image: Fig.3]

**Please note: when changing cell, change the code `A1` to the current cell.**

Comment: Hi @taylor.2317 and thanks for the suggestion. Sorry for the confusion of my example ,I showed only 10 values, but I have hundreds of matching values, and in Sheet1 they are not contiguous as in sheet2, and they repeat in Sheet1 so it's not desirable to use custom formulas for each value. That's why I need a script rather than manually setting each color for each value in the Conditional Formatting GUI. But anyway thank you for your answer.

Comment: oh, ok, apologies

Comment: Thanks, you made me realize I hade forgotten to say that values repeat, thanks for that! Here are screenshots of the repetition part: https://i.imgur.com/kK5kkFq.png https://i.imgur.com/QsQdaBH.png

Comment: I would also add these to your post if I were you.

Comment: Got them added thanks again!

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)